# Inequality involving difference of a power of 2 and 1

Tags: inequality, induction, exponential-function, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

For every natural number $n$ greater than $1$, prove that $2n – 1 \geq n \cdot 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$.

This was the question given in the book however simply plugging in $n=5$ we can see that the statement is false. And now my best guess is that it was a printing error and the actual question was about proving the following statement-

$$2^n – 1 \geq n \cdot 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$

Which now does seem to be true $\forall n$. But since I am new to inequalities i have no idea about dealing with inequalities involving negative numbers ( here "$-1$"). All help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can move the $-1$ to the other side if you prefer.  In any case, working from induction seems like a good idea.

Comment: Oh yess ofc induction. So many topics and theorems running through the mind i frequently forget the most important things lol.

Comment: As $n$ increases by $1$ the LHS almost doubles, while the RHS increases by a factor of just over $\sqrt2$. Eventually the LHS will win, and stay ahead.

Comment: Can someone please provide a formal proof using induction? I am unable to do that.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that:
$$2\cdot\left(2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)^2-n\cdot2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}-1\geq0$$ or
$$2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\geq\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}}{4},$$ which is true for $n=1$.

Now, by the assumption of the induction we obtain:
$$2^{\frac{n}{2}}=\sqrt2\cdot2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\geq\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}}{2\sqrt2}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+8}}{2\sqrt2}\geq\frac{n+1+\sqrt{n^2+2n+9}}{4},$$ which is true for any $n\geq1$.

Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a combinatorial approach. $2^n-1$ is the number of non-empty subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

We can choose a non-empty subset by first choosing the smallest number that appears, $k$, and then adding any subset of the $n-k$ larger numbers. Thus we get
$$2^n-1=\sum_{k=1}^n2^{n-k}.$$
Now the RHS has $n$ terms, and the average exponent is $\frac{n-1}2$. Thus Jensen's inequality gives
$$2^n-1=\sum_{k=1}^n2^{n-k}\geq n2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}.$$